# Export data as CSV format from SQLCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

All

I am looking for some help and guidence with a sqlcmd.  I found an article here how it could be done but my attempts to do it are failing so I am hoping someone can help and guide me...

I have a SQL query that looks like this...

---

```
USE lc_V3_acephoto_net
SELECT 
     Items.iID as product_id,
   Items.strSku as sku,
      s.ProductNumber as mpn
FROM Items left join POS..Skus s on Items.strSku=s.Sku
WHERE ISNULL(s.ProductNumber, '') <> '';`
```

---

[this is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaETm.jpg)

AS you can see see in the image, this provides me the output I need as long as I export it as a .CSV from SQL management Studio but I need to automate this, so it runs daily.

I found a post here and with that post I generated this command

```
sqlcmd -S 192.168.0.4 -U PAReadonly2 -P <password> -i "C:\Users\Amber\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Web Export Script.sql" -o "c:\export\SQLDump.csv" -h-1 -s"," -w 80
```

when I run this command it generates data but not what I wanted

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw4IS.jpg)

I am obviously doing something wrong with the formatting but I am new to this so I am hoping someone can provide me some guidance or how to make this simpler

thank for any help

I tried several flavors of this command and nothing seems to work for me.